# For each short eaxct sequence $0\to B\to C\to D\to 0$ there is a naturally associated exact sequence...

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

**I am trying to understand the proof in the hatcher topology book (pag $265$) on exact sequences ($6$):**

[image]

*What I don't understand is because when we use the zig-zag lemma we have the sequence we need. could someone explain to me please, thank you very much.*

**Edit:** What I mean is that according to what is said in Hatcher's book, using the exact sequence given $0\to B\to C\to D\to 0$, I can build an exact chain complex $0\to F_*\otimes B\to F_*\otimes C\to F_*\otimes D\to 0$, so if I use the zigzag lemma, I get an exact sequence $...\to H_n(F_*\otimes B)\to H_n(F_*\otimes C)\to H_n(F_*\otimes D)\to H_{n-1}(F_*\otimes B)\to ...$ but how can I get what I want from this last sequence? Thank you.

Comment: which Tor do you mean? I presume the first one, or do you mean the whole Tor complex? If second, that does not make sense, if the first, you will need some more properties for A,B,C or your cat, as I can guarantee there exist objects with higher tor, which would crash your argument

Comment: @Enkidu What I mean is that according to what is said in Hatcher's book, using the exact sequence given $0\to B\to C\to D\to 0$, I can build an exact chain complex $0\to F_*\otimes B\to F_*\otimes C\to F_*\otimes D\to 0$, so if I use the zigzag lemma, I get an exact sequence $...\to H_n(F_*\otimes B)\to H_n(F_*\otimes C)\to H_n(F_*\otimes D)\to H_{n-1}(F_*\otimes B)\to ...$ but how can I get what I want from this last sequence? Thank you.

Comment: First, Hatcher is dealing with abelian groups. That is why you only see $Tor=Tor_1$ not $Tor_i$. I will assume that you understand why the horizontal sequences are exact which is basically by $F_i$ being free and use tensor direct sum natural commutation relation. Now to get induced long exact sequence, you look induced vertical arrows which may have non-trivial kernels and must have cokernels. Those kernels are $Tor_1(A,-)$ with $-=B,C,D$. Cokernel $(-)\otimes A$ with $-=B,C,D$ is obtained by right exactness of tensor functor $-\otimes A$. To see the map, you just apply snake lemma.